# Entity Framework with edmx file error

Tags: xml, entity-framework-6, designer

I am having an error with an EF project in C# (model first) where it is complaining about

> Value cannot be null. Parameter Name propertyMapping

It also shows up when I open the `.edmx` file in the XML editor in visual studio, but I can't find out where it is coming from.

I tried to find out what schema the error is coming from, and I can't seem to find it.

Here is a link to the `.edmx` file: http://pastebin.com/XTP7TsUu

If anyone has an idea on how to create a small repo of the problem, i'd be happy to do that.

Also, if other files need to be uploaded, let me know.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: [Restart Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12378670/861716)

Comment: @GertArnold Did not work

Comment: I'm afraid you have to retrace your steps to the point where everything was still OK.

Comment: @GertArnold How? I restarted VS, and now it won't open in the designer